# Can I use a kind of css variables?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to tidy all my css code on my site, I want to be able to be specific with the type. Let's say the type will be 20px, bold and blue e.g.

```
<h1 bold blue>Hello world</h1 blue bold>
```

So the css file will have:

```
h1 {
font-size:20px;
}

bold {
font-weight:bold:
}

blue {
color:blue;
}
```

Then as I go through my design process i can mix and match with colors and sizes etc. Is something like this possible?

Comment: You can do this with classes, but it's hardly (read: never) a good idea to pollute your markup with decorative attributes and classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this isn't possible exaclty like you want to, but what you can do is this:

```
<h1 bold blue>Hello world</h1 blue bold> // your idea
<h1 class="bold blue">Hello world</h1>   // correct html, even slightly shorter
```

and

```
h1 {
  font-size:20px;
}

.bold {                                  // added . for being a class
  font-weight:bold:
}

.blue {                                  // added . for being a class
  color:blue;
}
```

css-variables itself are possible when using something like [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/), but this works in another way than the one you mentioned and your html-markup still has to be valid.

**EDIT:**
please note that, as [edem (and others) said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923340/288773), using `blue` and `bold` as classnames in a real project isn't a good idea. i assumed you just gave this as short examples to ask for how to combine different "sets of css-rules" (read: classes). if thats not the case: stick to [edems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923340/288773) or [tims explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923311/288773) and take a look at guides for "semantical markup".

Comment: @edem: you're absolutely right, but i assumed `blue` and `bold` are just short examples to clearify he want's to combine different classes - maybe i should have mentioned that.

Comment: +1 for "even slightly shorter". I totally agree with edem and tim-medora, but this example is both clear and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Colors rarely make good identifiers. Suppose "blue" is no longer blue? Maybe you want it to be red instead?

Font-weights ("bold" in your example) also are not good identifiers. Perhaps in the future you may prefer a font which looks better with a normal font-weight.

Determine the purpose of the style (e.g. article byline, or picture caption) and/or the semantic purpose of the element to which it is being applied, and name your styles accordingly.

You can then use a combination of classes (as others have mentioned) to achieve your desired goal.

Answer (score 3):

This is against good practices. Let's say you have an article header type which can be found on any article page and a main header which is on every page:

```
.mainHeader {
   font-size:20px;
   font-weight:bold:
   color:blue;
}

.articleHeader {
   font-size:15px;
   font-weight:bold:
   color:red;
}
```

What if some day you decide that your article header won't be blue any more. If you change

```
.blue {
  color:blue;
}
```

to

```
.blue {
    color:red;
}
```

that wont'be good. You should name your classes/ids according to their semantical purpose.

The point is that CSS supposed to be succint so you can change the looks of your whole page with modification in 1-2 lines. The idea you present here is not succint therefore not considered a good practice.

I think you should use [less css](http://lesscss.org/) as the answer suggested above. By the way if you use some scripting language on your webpage like python or php you can use a template engine which supports inheritance and you can generate your own css code and you can use variables there. This simply does not fit in CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use classes.

```
<h1 class"bold blue">Hello world</h1>

h1 {font-size:20px;}

.bold {
    font-weight:bold:
}

.blue {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Using .bold or .blue is not a good practice since it can change to some other color / font type at any time if you decide that it does not look good any more and in that case .blue {color:red} is not so meaningful.